# akka cluster slave node not joining seed node

Tags: akka

I am working with akka distributed worker template available on typesafe. I am using it to write a backend job which takes data from siebel using soap calls and inserts in mongo. This job is supposed to run once a week for few hours.

Based on the cluster-usage and other documentation on AKKA website, I imported akka-cluster.jar and configured the application configuration file with SEED nodes (akka.cluster.seed-nodes). But when I start the first node (MASTER NODE) with the configuration I mentioned (seed nodes etc), I start getting errors on the server console saying failed to join the seed node which is obvious (as it is the first node and there is nothing to join). Now I start the second node with akka.cluster.seed-nodes configured with the ip-address and port of the process where master node is running. I once again get the errors on the server console.

Now what I do next is - take the first join address of the master actor  from the MASTER NODE and set it dynamically in the slave node in the code (construct an Address object and pass it to the actors on the slave node). THIS WORKS!!! If I take the same join address and configure it in the application configuration akka.cluster.seed-nodes, it throws me error and slave doesn't join the cluster.

So I have following questions :-
1. How to configure the akka.cluster.seed-node configuration in application. I could never make it work/count in the configuration.
2. Is there any way to pre-configure the seed nodes in the configuration. As per me trying it out, it looks like the configuration is dynamic i.e. to take the join address of actor on the master node from the logs and configure the slave's seed-node configuration with that address ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems which were the result of a mismatch between the actor system name in the seed nodes configuration and the actual actor system name created in my code.